# Parse server login using REST API

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm trying to sign in with parse by REST API, always getting response as "Cannot GET /parse/1/login?username=user123&password=parse123") **404** . Below is my code

```
var auth_data={
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  "X-Parse-Revocable-Session": "1",
  "X-Parse-Application-Id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "X-Parse-Master-Key": "xxxxxxxxxx"

}
var res = $http.get('https://subodha.indiearts.in/parse/1/login?username=user123&password=parse123', auth_data);
    res.then(function (response) {
        $log.info(response);
    }).catch(function (error) {
        $log.error(error);
    });
```

Am I missing anything??

Comment: Why do you start riding a dead horse? The Parse.com server will be shut down end of January 2017.

Comment: @Robert: May be you have to see the code with caution. It's my own server.

Comment: `api.parse.com` is your own server?

Comment: @Robert: LOL. I forgotten to update the question. I did it now.

Answer (score 1):

This is becasue your `get` url is wrong. With parse-server your url should be

```
yourdomain/parse/login
```

and not

```
yourdomain/parse/1/login
```

Remove the 1